# MongoDB "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' error"

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm new to NoSQL MongoDb databases and trying to extract some data where there are no fraud transactions and group them by state name and count using aggregate function

I tried writing some queries but it seems like match function and group function are not working together, below is I had so far, any help is appreciated

**Code:**

```py
from pprint import pprint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pymongo as pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
mydatabase = client.project
collection = mydatabase.CS532

results = collection.aggregate([     
    {
        "Merchent State" : { "$exists": "true" }
    },

    {
    "$match":{
        {
            "Is Fraud?" : "No",
        }
        }
    },

    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id": "$Merchant State", "count":{
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    },

    {
        "$sort": {
            "count": -1
        }
    },
    
    {
        "$limit" : 3
    }
])

for x in results:
    pprint(x)
```

**Error:**

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karthiktvs/DB_project/hello.py", line 21, in <module>
    "$match":{
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: If you replace the first 2 stages with `{"$match": {"Merchent State" : {"$exists": "true"}, "Is Fraud?" : "No"}}`, does it do what you want then?

Comment: FYI, the error message is due to `{'$match': {{'Is Fraud?': 'No'}}}`.  The double `{{..}}` is not valid python here, regardless of MongoDB/pymongo.  You might want to do something like `pipeline = [ ... ]` and then `cursor = collection.aggregate(pipeline)`.  If there are python errors assigning `pipeline`, it will make it easier to identify.

Comment: Thank you, after modifying the code it is working now